# Can JSDoc link to source line?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, jsdoc3

Is there some way to get jsdoc to link directly to the line in the source code file instead of just to the beginning of the file?

[image: Screenshot of link text]

Answer (score 0):

Ah! Simple answer after looking at JSDoc's generated html. I just needed to click the line number instead of the html filename. (Just in case someone else is as new to JSDoc)

Comment: Yet you even took care of highlighting the line number in the screenshot...